# How to have git stats on a diff file?

Tags: git, patch, git-diff, diffstat

While in a git repository, I can do :

```
git log --oneline --stat
```

and I'll have a nice output looking like:

```
ca0ab77 commit message
a/file/changed | 19 -------------------
1 file changed, 19 deletions(-)
```

In my case, I am working outside a git repository and I only have the .diff (the output of `git diff <commit-ish>`) files and I would like to have the same stats (Files changed, additions, deletions).

Is there a tool to do it ? Or should I write a regex ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The histogram with +/- signs and the "1 file changed, ..." is known as the diffstat. The `diffstat` tool ([man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/diffstat)) can produce these if you feed it your diff:

```
$ diffstat -p1 my-patch.diff
src/some_file.c |    4 ++--
1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
```

If you only want the last line, use `-s`:

```
$ diffstat -s my-patch.diff
1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
```

Using `-p1` is probably a good idea if you're feeding it git diffs which have a/b prefixes. If you don't use `-p`, diffstat strips common prefixes from the filenames. Sometimes this can give you unexpected results (especially if your patch adds or deletes files by comparing them with `/dev/null`).

Diffstat can also give you coloured histograms if you use the `-C` option.